# How to prove that directory is a file in Linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

*"Everything is a file in Linux"*. How can i prove that directories are represented as files in linux. Also the physical hardware devices everything creates and is represented as files in Linux. But how can i prove this concept with supporting examples to someone.

Viewing the Directory and other physical hardwares as files in Liniux.( POC)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Everything is a file in Linux" statement is a bit of an oversimplification. There are many things in Linux that appear as files, but don't quite 'act' as you think they would in a conventional sense.

Block files (e.g. `/dev/loop0`) are a great example of this as they are used as a way of communicating with device drivers.

That said, directories are their own 'special' kind of file that contain inode ids pointing to a file's inode. I suppose a simple 'proof' of sorts would be to `ls -l` any directory and you will notice that most (if not all) of them will have a listed file size of 4096 bytes rather than listing the collective size of its contents.

4096 bytes is the smallest blocksize for most filesystems and is usually more than enough to fit all the information (inode ids) of a directory. So rather than direct information/access to its files, a directory rather holds meta-data about them.

Alternatively, using `stat` on any directory will display it's own inode number (as well as the number of links it has).

EDIT: Directory files contain the *inode id* (a pointer to a file's inode) not the inode itself. I have edited the answer.

Comment: actually they contain names pointing to inodes. inodes are not in the directory, thus one inode can be in several directories.

Comment: I stand corrected. Thank you and I have updated the answer.